# how to use string variable as datatype name in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of words:

```
List<string> listofwords;

public void list()
{
   listofwords = new List<string>();
   listofwords.Add("tackle");
   listofwords.Add("hinder");
   listofwords.Add("mentor");
}
```

Each word contains multiple data in it:

```
public List<string> tackle;
public List<string> hinder;
public List<string> mentor;

public void A()
{  
   mentor = new List<string>();
   mentor.Add("tern");
   mentor.Add("tome");
   mentor.Add("tone");

   tackle = new List<string>();
   tackle.Add("alce");
   tackle.Add("cake");
   tackle.Add("calk");
   tackle.Add("cate");
   tackle.Add("kale");
   tackle.Add("lace");

   hinder = new List<string>();
   hinder.Add("deni");
   hinder.Add("dine");
 }
```

In the button click event, I want to check a list. The list's name is stored in a string variable *val*:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (val.Contains(textBox1.Text )))
      val.Remove(textBox1.Text);
}
```

How do I use *val* to check the list?

Comment: `List.Contains` should work. Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 6):

Consider using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) for this problem. The key type should be `String` and the value type should be `List<String>`.

Your code would look something like this:

```
_listOfWords = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
_listOfWords.Add("mentor", new List<String>
                                    {
                                        "tern",
                                        "tome",
                                        "tone"
                                    });
_listOfWords.Add("tackle", new List<String>
                                    {
                                        "alce",
                                        "cake",
                                        // etc.
                                    });
```

You can then get the "data" for words from the dictionary. `List<String> list = _listOfWords[val];` and do with it as you please.

Comment: You really should consider giving a code sample detailing what your answer is.  -1 until you do.

Comment: I didn't see it when I gave the down vote.  +1 now that you added a code sample.